# Nightmare JavaScript document not defined error

Tags: javascript, nightmare

I've got the code below, and I'm trying to go to W3Schools, take all the links, check if the titles are the same as the pages, but I need to go through all the pages of the search and I cannot seem to do that.

Can you help me? Also if there is any change of the code please let me know. I get the error:

```
document not defined
```

and I don't understand why.

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare');
const nightmare = Nightmare({
  show: true
});

let Promise = require('bluebird');

return start();

function itExists() {
  var element = document.querySelector("#pnnext > span:nth-child(2)");
  if (typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

async function start() {
  await nightmare
    .goto('https://www.google.com')
    .type('#lst-ib', 'w3schools')
    .click('#tsf > div.tsf-p > div.jsb > center > input[type="submit"]:nth-child(1)');
  while (itExists()) {
    const linkuri = await nightmare.evaluate(() => {
        let urls = document.querySelectorAll('div.rc>.r>a');
        let linkuri = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; ++i) {
          item = {};
          item["title"] = urls[i].innerHTML;
          item["link"] = urls[i].href;
          linkuri.push(item);
        }
        return linkuri;
      })
      .click("#pnnext > span:nth-child(2)");
  }
  return selectare(linkuri);
}

async function selectare(linkuri) {
  await Promise.each(linkuri, async(link) => {
    await nightmare
      .goto(link.link)
      .wait(1000)
      .evaluate(function() {
        return document.title;
      })
      .then(function(title) {
        if (title === link.title) {
          console.log(title + " = " + link.link + " " + link.title);
        } else {
          console.log(title + " != " + link.link + " " + link.title);
        }
      })
  })
}
```

Comment: From what it looks like, you're running your code on node.js, in this case there will be no document, it is a browser API.

Comment: Yeah so how do i actually manage to get this to pass through all the pages and check the  push the links into the linkuri array , that's what im trying to do

Comment: Well this is a broad question that you are asking, meaning it can probably be done in many ways, I guess you need some more research now that you know why this code is not working. Where did you find it?

Comment: You may try to use browserify to compile this code and run it in the browser, you may need babel for async/await I am not sure (mdn the async/await) but browerserify is a fifty/fifty. It may not work here. Depending on how this nightmare is implemented and how heavily it relies on node Api.

Comment: I haven't found it , I wrote it myself but I need it for a test and I can't seem to figure out how to go through al lthe pages I've updated it and now i've got the Next working but cannot seem to figure out how to get the data from each page

Comment: the only place where you can use "document" is inside the evaluate callback, it doesn't exist outside of it. Check out nightmare .wait() function, it can wait until an element exists.